# Rails Model not found when importing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models being discussed here:

```
class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :park

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :slugged_name_and_park, use: :slugged

    delegate :name,
    to: :park,
    allow_nil: true,
    prefix: true

    def slugged_name_and_park
        name.parameterize + '-' + park_name.parameterize
    end
end
```

```
class Park < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rides
end
```

I then have a custom import script that uses `Roo` to iterate rows in an Excel file to fill my database.

Importing Parks:

```
park = Park.find_or_create_by(
    name: parks_data[:name],
    location_1: parks_data[:location_1],
)
```

Importing Rides:

```
    ride = Ride.find_or_create_by!(
        name: rides_data[:name],
        park: Park.find_by!(
            name: rides_data[:park],
            location_1: rides_data[:location_1]
        ),
        position: rides_data[:position],
        style: rides_data[:type]
    )
```

The issue us that, when it starts importing the first ride, it is trying to find the Park and comes back with "Cannot find Park".

The park 100% exists. I have also been into the console and run `Park.find_by(name: 'x', location_1: 'y')` and it gets returned with no issues.

I also have another model that links itself to a Park in the same way and uses the same code and that works perfectly, but this one fails.  Really cannot figure out why.

Can anyone spot some other reason as to why the Ride cannot find the associated Park then I am just not spotting?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: There's no magic. If a park exists, it will be returned. If strings are visibly the same, check for invisible differences in the data, like trailing whitespace/newlines or weird unicode unprintable characters.

Comment: @Eyeslandic Ok, How can I check the SQL?  Is there something I can use to output it?

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev Thanks.  I'll do another check.  As far as I can tell, the strings are technically as well as visibly identical?

Comment: @Eyeslandic Also, this import script is being run as a background job.  The output I see in my terminal window is very condensed and minimal compared to when not being in a job.  Can I change it so the output is more verbose and detailed?

Comment: Managed to FINALLY track down the error.  And what a stupid error it was.  I had accidentally duplicated the location_1 column in my spreadsheet but it was on the far right of many columns sat their empty and this breaking the find_by clause.  Many thanks to you both for helping me to track it down!